# Evaluating $\log_{ab} \left(\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)$, given the values of $\log_xa$, $\log_xb$, $\log_xc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I am totally drawing a blank on how you would go about solving this.

> Let's say you have the following equations:
> $$\begin{align}\log_x a &= 4.22 \\
>  \log_x b &= 3.7 \\
>  \log_x c &= 2.41
>  \end{align}$$
>
> How would you go about evaluating this?
>
> $$\log_{ab} \left(\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)$$

Comment: Look for rules for logarithm: base change, product, quotient etc, For example: $\log_bP+\log_bQ=\log_b(PQ)$

Comment: You may want to use the fact that $\log_a x = \dfrac 1 {\log_x a}. \qquad$

Comment: Consider $\log_y z=\frac{\ln z}{\ln y}$, together with $\ln (yz)=\ln y+\ln z$,$\ \ $ $\ln \left(\frac yz\right)=\ln y-\ln z$, $\ \ $ $\ln \left(y^z\right)=z\ln y$ make things much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_{ab} \left(\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)
 =\frac{\log_x\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}}{\log_x ab}
 =\frac{\log_x x^2+\frac13\log_x a-\log_x b-3\log_xc}{\log_x a+\log_x b}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are many logarithm laws at your disposal.

\begin{align*}
\log_{ab}\left(\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)&=\log_{ab}(x^2\sqrt[3]{a})-\log_{ab}(bc^3)\\
&=\log_{ab}(x^2)+\log_{ab}(\sqrt[3]{a})-(\log_{ab}(b)+\log_{ab}(c^3))\\
&=2\log_{ab}(x)+\frac{1}{3}\log_{ab}(a)-\log_{ab}(b)-3\log_{ab}(c)\\
&=2\frac{\log_x(x)}{\log_xab}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{\log_x(a)}{\log_xab}-\frac{\log_x(b)}{\log_xab}-3\frac{\log_x(c)}{\log_xab}\\
&=\frac{2}{\log_xa+\log_xb}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{\log_x(a)}{\log_xa+\log_xb}-\frac{\log_x(b)}{\log_xa+\log_xb}\\&-3\frac{\log_x(c)}{\log_xa+\log_xb}
\end{align*}

Then, you can plug your values in.

Comment: Familiar with `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` ? )

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Vaguely - I didn't want to experiment and screw the answer up.

Comment: You can rollback my edit then

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help! It certainly looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Considering every equation is well defined, from first three equations, you get
$$a=x^{4.22}\qquad b=x^{3.7}\qquad c=x^{2.41}$$ Now find $$\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}$$in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $x^{4.22} = a,$ $x^{3.7} = b,$ $x^{2.41} = c. $ So
\begin{align}
& \log_{ab} \left(\frac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right) = \log_{ab}\left( \frac{x^2 \sqrt[3]{x^{4.22}}}{x^{3.7} ( x^{2.41})^3} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \log_{ab}\left( x^2\cdot x^{4.22/3} \cdot x^{-3.7} \cdot x^{-2.41\cdot 3} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \log_{ab} \left( x^{2 + 4.22/3 -3.7 -(2.41\cdot3)} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( 2 + \frac{4.22} 3 - 3.7 -(2.41\cdot 3) \right) \log_{ab}x \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{2 + \frac{4.22} 3 - 3.7 -(2.41\cdot 3)}{\log_x (ab)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{6 + 4.22 - 11.1 - (2.41\cdot 9)}{3\log_x(ab)} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{6 + 4.22 - 11.1 - (2.41\cdot 9)}{3\log_x(x^{4.22}\cdot x^{3.7}) } \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{6 + 4.22 - 11.1 - (2.41\cdot 9)}{3\log_x(x^{4.22+3.7}) } \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{6 + 4.22 - 11.1 - (2.41\cdot 9)}{3(4.22+3.7) }
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The basic equation is
$\log_a(b)
=\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(a)}
$
where the logs on the right
can be done to any base
as long as they are the same.

So, for your equations,
replacing the constants
with variables.
we have

$\dfrac{\log(a)}{\log(x)}
=u\\
\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(x)}
=v\\
\dfrac{\log(c)}{\log(x)}
=w\\
$

Dividing these,

$\dfrac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}
=\dfrac{u}{v}\\
\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(c)}
=\dfrac{v}{w}\\
\dfrac{\log(c)}{\log(a)}
=\dfrac{w}{u}\\
$

and you want

$\begin{array}\\
\log_{ab} \left(\dfrac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)
&=\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{x^2\sqrt[3]{a}}{bc^3}\right)}{\log(ab) }\\
&=\dfrac{\log(x^2\sqrt[3]{a})-\log(bc^3)}{\log(ab)}\\
&=\dfrac{2\log(x)+\log(a)/3-\log(b)-3\log(c)}{\log(ab)}\\
&=\dfrac{2\log(x)}{\log(ab)}+\dfrac{\log(a)}{3\log(ab)}-\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(ab)}-\dfrac{3\log(c)}{\log(ab)}\\
\end{array}
$

Now use
$\dfrac{\log(g)}{\log(ab)}
=\dfrac1{\dfrac{\log(ab)}{\log(g)}}
=\dfrac1{\dfrac{\log(a)+\log(b)}{\log(g)}}
=\dfrac1{\dfrac{\log(a)}{\log(g)}+\dfrac{\log(b)}{\log(g)}}
$
with the different ratios above
to get these expressions
in terms of
$u, v, $ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

You're given everything in terms of $\log_x$, so just use the fact that $\log_y z = \dfrac{\log_x z}{\log_x y}$:

$$\log_{ab}\frac{x^2a^{1/3}}{bc^3}=\frac{\log_x \frac{x^2a^{1/3}}{bc^3}}{\log_x ab}$$
Then just expand with the usual rules for products, quotients, and powers:
$$= \frac{2\log_x x + \frac13\log_x a - \log_x b - 3\log_x c}{\log_x a + \log_x b}$$
Now plug in the values you are given:
$$= \frac{2(1) + \frac13(4.22) - 3.7 - 3(2.41)}{4.22 + 3.7}$$
$$\approx-0.9499$$
If you want an exact value instead of an approximation, it's $-\frac{2257}{2376}$ (this can't be reduced since $2257$ is prime). You can get that by clearing fractions in that numerical expression; just multiply top and bottom by $300$ to clear the $\frac13$ and the decimal fractions.